# Why does writeUTFBytes mess up non-english characters?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm writing all sorts of multi lingual text to .txt files using AIR's

`fileStream.writeUTFBytes()`

For english characters everything works perfectly. But as soon as there are chinese, arabic or any other non-english characters the sentences are totally messed up.

For example:

**对着大叔摄影师的确没爱....**

becomes

**ÂØπÁùÄÂ§ßÂèîÊëÑÂΩ±Â∏àÁöÑÁ°ÆÊ≤°Áà±....**

How can this be fixed?

Comment: How do you check the contents of the file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But I'm getting the text from the web via an API.

Comment: does your font support non latin characters (have you embedded them all?)

Comment: @shortstick: Should that really matter? The text is never displayed anywhere. It's downloaded from the internet and I'm using fileStream.writeUTFBytes() to write it to a .txt file using AIR.

Comment: ah right... whats the encoding of the imported file?

Comment: @shortstick: No file is imported in this case. The data is returned in an XML file after an API call. The XML is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: is the source of the API call in UTF-8?

Comment: @shortstick: Yes, it's a Flickr API call and all results are UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

writeUTFBytes doesn't mess up anything since it doesn't process the content.
Whatever goes in the pipe comes out.

The text you are sending is most likely encoded in Unicode/UTF-8
Make sure that you are openning the file with an editor that supports unicode (even Windows Notepad supports it, but it defaults to ANSI).